# Run a background notification function on clipboard changed even in Android Oreo

Tags: java, android, service

I want to run a background function which listens to the clipboard and when a string greater than 200 characters is copied then it will execute the function to show notification and then the proper `Activity.class`.

I am unable to create a service which runs in the background all the time even when the app is closed and the phone is restarted. Current I am starting that function in `MyApp` class which extends `Application` as I am unable to understand any tutorial based on services which can give me what I want.

Below is my code for `MyApp`

**MyApp.class**

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

private PrefManager prefManager;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    prefManager = new PrefManager(this);
    if (prefManager.isNotifOns()) {
        getClipTexts();
    }
}



//Listener to listen change in clipboard
private void getClipTexts() {
    final ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    clipboardManager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {

            try {

                String textToPaste = clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).getText().toString();
                if (textToPaste.length() > 200) {

                    makeNotification(textToPaste);


                }
            } catch (Exception ignored) {

            }


        }
    });
}


//Creating notifications after copying the clipboard text
public void makeNotification(String input) {


    Intent notifIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PostActivity.class);
    notifIntent.putExtra("post", input);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    int notificationId = 1;
    String channelId = "channel-01";
    String channelName = "Copy to Post";
    int importance = 0;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
    }

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                channelId, channelName, importance);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Post copied content")
            .setContentText(input)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getApplicationContext());
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notifIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());


}
}
```

Can anyone please write this function in a service which runs in background and supports in all Android Versions.

The above code does what I want as long as the app is running on foreground but I want to run the function even when App is closed or phone is restarted even in android versions above Android N.  Please give me a proper answer I will be thankful for that.

Comment: U got any solve for this? And how about a forever running notification?